# May a Chinese citizen visit Hong Kong for five days?

Tags: hong-kong

I am a U.S. citizen traveling to Hong Kong for one week, My friend is a Chinese citizen and lives in Beijing. Is she allowed to freely travel to Hong Kong for five days? If not, what does she need to do in order to visit Hong Kong?

Comment: What is the citizenship of your friend? Is she "mainland Chinese" or which nationality does she have? Note that the answer to your question crucially depends that.

Answer (score 1):

If she is not transiting Hong Kong to/from a foreign country, then it seems she will need a [Two-way Permit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People's_Republic_of_China_Exit-Entry_Permit_for_Travelling_to_and_from_Hong_Kong_and_Macau).